# ArrayList error when using Generic Types

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

When running the following code, I get the error:

> add(java.lang.Integer) in ArrayList cannot be applied to java.lang.Integer[]

If I don't use a Generic Type in the ArrayList, it runs just fine. I don't really understand the error, as both the arrayList and the array are Integers. What am I missing? Thank you!

```
        ArrayList<Integer> recyclingCrates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int houses[] = new int[8];
        int sum = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            System.out.println("How many recycling crates were set out at house " + x + "?");
            houses[x] = scanner.nextInt();
            for (Integer n : recyclingCrates){
                houses[x]=n;
            }
        }

        recyclingCrates.add(houses); //this is where I get the error
```

Comment: So you think an `int[]` is the same as an `Integer`? Or do you think a `ArrayList<Integer>` is the same as a `int[]`? Have you read the javadoc of `ArrayList#add`?

Comment: Note: your code has other problems not covered by this question. I don't think it will give you the results you expect, even after fixing *this* problem.

Answer (score 1):

`add` adds a *single element* to a list. If your call succeeded, it would add an array reference to the list - not the contents of the array - and then the list would contain a single element (which is the reference).

Assuming that you want to keep your existing code structure for some reason (instead of adding the elements individually inside the loop):

To add the *contents* of the array to the list, use `Arrays.asList` to "wrap" the array in a `List`, then use `addAll`:

```
recyclingCrates.addAll(Arrays.asList(houses));
```

You will also need to change the type of `houses` to `Integer[]` - otherwise, `Arrays.asList` would need to return a `List<int>`, which isn't possible. (You can also use it as `Arrays.asList(thing1, thing2, thing3)` to return a list containing `thing1`, `things2` and `thing3` - and this syntax will be used instead, returning a list containing only a single array reference, which would be back to where you started!)

Comment: Ah, that would explain why my code seemed to work after I did this:  for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                System.out.println("How many recycling crates were set out at house " + x + "?");
                houses[x] = scanner.nextInt();
                recyclingCrates.add(houses[x]);
            }
Knowing it only adds a single element makes what's going on a lot clearer, thank you!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oops, I assumed it was an Integer[] because that's what the quoted error message says.